# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Blusson Hall'

Tags: python, spaces

This *is* homework but I'm not looking for a handout. Error messages haven't really been explained yet so I don't know how to fix this or why it's happening. I know it happens when I try to make s into an integer but I get a different error if I don't so I'm a little lost... 
I've also tried looking at some of the other posts with similar problems but I'm very new to Python and I can't follow the explanations.

It's a pretty straightforward function, I think. 
I've tried converting it to an integer to I can perform the range function on it but that doesn't seem to be working. The program is supposed to first put a space between the letters in "Blusson Hall" and add an additional space if there is already one there and finally print that design around the final product. Thanks for any help.

```
def spaced(s):
   n = int (s)
   for [i] in range (n):
      if [i] != " ":
         n == n+ [i] + " "
      if [i] == " ":
         n == n+ [i] + " "
    print "-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-"
    print ".                             ."
    print "-  "   +  str (n)+ " -"
    print ".                             ."
    print "-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-"



      #- you write (5 marks) -#
      ###################
      #- Tester's code -#
      ###################

      spaced("Blusson Hall")
```

Comment: Nothing you've written here really makes any sense. What are you trying to do, exactly? For one thing, you seem to be trying to treat `[i]` as a variable name; you can't have square brackets in a variable name.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are calling `spaced` with a non-numeric string and then trying to convert that to an integer:

```
>>> int("Blusson Hall")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Blusson Hall'
```

If you want a range based on the length of the string, you can use something like:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
```

as in:

```
>>> s = "Busson Hall"
>>> for i in range(len(s)):
...     print i
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And, as some extra assistance, you would use `s[i]` to get the `i`'th (zero being the first one, of course) character of `s`. In addition, you probably want to start with an empty string and then append individual characters to it (from the original string and whatever spaces you want added) to gradually build it up before returning it.

For example, this snippet duplicates every character with a colon between them:

```
>>> s = "paxdiablo"
>>> s2 = ""
>>> for i in range(len(s)):
...     s2 = "%s%s:%s:" % (s2, s[i], s[i])
...
>>> print s2
p:p:a:a:x:x:d:d:i:i:a:a:b:b:l:l:o:o:
```

Short of writing the code for you (which, intelligently, you decided against asking for), that's probably all the help I can give (though feel free to ask any questions you want and I'll offer further advice).

Comment: Oh wow! I expected to get an e-mail notification about any responses so I never checked back. xD 
Thank you so much for the responses, I think this will really help me study for my final.

Answer (score 2):

i think i see the issue.

instead of

```
n = int(s)
```

try

```
n = len(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a string to an integer, and that's what you try to do when you type:

```
n = int(s)
```

spaced only takes one argument, 's', and you pass in a string, then try to convert it to an integer. I think what you want is probably

```
n = len(s)
```

But really, you don't even need that. Since strings are iterable, you can just loop over it like:

```
for ch in s:
      ...do stuff here...
```

And if the index within s for each char is helpful/easier, enumerate() will do that for you:

```
   for idx, ch in enumerate(s):
       ...do stuff here...
```

Just so you know, you don't actually need a for loop at all. Since strings are iterable and 'join()' takes an iterable as an argument, you can replace almost all of your code with this:

```
' '.join(s)
```

That looks odd if you haven't done much with Python before. I've created a string ' ', and join() is a method that all strings have available. Join takes some iterable object (like a list, or even another string) and puts the string that is the object of the join between each element of the iterable. So, in this case, it puts ' ' between each element of the string 's'.

Comment: It'd be nice to know why I was -1'd here. Is there a problem with the answer?